# Is it possible to cache, client-side, dynamically created files?

Tags: javascript, caching, dynamic, websocket

I'm working on a websocket based project. The main server, which includes both a web and websocket server, mainly acts as a forwarding hub to other websocket servers. These secondary websocket servers are not expected to also have web servers running, but are expected to be hosting files that may or may not need to be downloaded (transferred directly via websocket depending on need).

While the files aren't expected to be very large--current test file hovers around 2KB, but we expect a standard of around 10-20KB, and possibly much larger if we allow encoding of images and other data-heavy material--files are expected to be demanded from an array of hosts repeatedly. That is, clients may 'request' a file from multiple, independent websocket servers (not at the same time). However, it would be expected a single client may request the same file from a single websocket server as much as 20 times a day or more.

So, to cut down on bandwidth, I am wondering if it is possible to cache these dynamic files doing purely client-side work.

Answer (score 0):

With HTML5 You can leverage the browsers Application Cache by using a Manifest.

In such a manifest you can specify files which should be cached on the clientside. Invalidation of these caches happens through Javascript so that is also on the clientside.

More on Application Cache and manifest files you'll find here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Comment: I looked into Manifests, but doesn't it require files be transferred by a traditional HTTP file server?

Comment: Don't know, you could try. And if that doesn't work you can also store data in the application cache manually: http://html5doctor.com/storing-data-the-simple-html5-way-and-a-few-tricks-you-might-not-have-known/